# is Google developer fee is necessary in order to upload a web extension to Google's web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I just finished creating my first google web extension and I want to upload it to the google web extension store (i completed all the screenshot and logos etc... ). as I saw in a tutorial, uploading the extension supposed to be totally free. this is why I was surprised to see that it actually requires `5$` to upload your first extension. I suspect I have done something wrong. the extension is for free so no "google cuts" should be charged. are the fees necessary and can it be avoided?

Comment: Uploading is free. Verification is $5. It's mandatory. There's no workaround.

Comment: @wOxxOm so how I can upload without Verification?

Comment: @wOxxOm I hit 'public' ant it says:

Comment: @wOxxOm Before you publish your first item, you must pay a one-time US$5.00 developer registration fee. We charge this fee in order to verify developer accounts and better protect users against fraudulent activity.

Once you have paid the registration fee you can publish up to 20 items.
We use Google Payments to process the US$5.00 payment. We'll ask you to provide your billing information if you haven't used Google Payments before.

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: @wOxxOm I even tried to create a new account just to see if it is some sort of 'black list' of googles  mail that has to pay and didn't work in the new one as well

Comment: @avivgood3 He told you twice already: there is no way to avoid the fee. You have to pay the fee.  Everyone who wants to publish an extension in the store does; it has nothing to do with you as an individual or any hypothetical blacklist. Your original understanding that it was free was incorrect.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't want Verification. just upload. you said its free

Comment: @avivgood3 To upload you have to verify. It’s a requirement; wOxxOm told you this with his first comment. Google’s message you quoted told you why verification is required. You have to pay the fee.

Comment: @DanBron ok. I'm sorry. I thought that it is not necessary